# Error With Soap Using Magento API's

Tags: web-services, api, soap, wsdl, magento-1.7

OK, so we've just migrated a Magento 1.7.0.2 installation to a new server. We had a WSDL service running fine on the old server which stopped working on the new one.

When I load the XML file it queries, I am presented with this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
<faultstring>
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://mydomain.com/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://mydomain.com/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1"
</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

All the files were transferred like for like and everything else worked just fine.

I think it's potentially something to do with file permissions but frankly I have no Idea!

I'm banging my head against the desk, can anyone shed some light?